# Concatenating 2 array variable names to create a new variable name

Tags: php, array

I'm developing a room booking system using PHP for a school project.

I'm trying to create a variable name by concatenating values from two arrays together. 
here are the two arrays:

```
$day = array('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri');
$B = array('P1B', 'P2B', 'P3B', 'P4B', 'P5B', 'P6B');
```

and then here is the code I'm currently using to try concatenate them:

```
// getting all the values from the table using $_POST. There are 120 different values so it is best to create these variables using a procedure

for ($l = 0; $l < count($day); ++$l) {
    for ($k = 0; $k < count($B); ++$k) {
        $days = $day[$l];
        $week = $B[$k];
        ${$days . $week} = $_POST["'" . $days.$week . "'"];
    };
};
```

Is the syntax of the concatenated variable correct? Is there a better way of doing this?

The final variable names of the concatenated variable should look something like:

```
$MonP1B
$MonP2B
$MonP3B
$MonP4B
$MonP5B
$MonP6B
$TueP1B
```

etc.

Comment: This is a really bad idea, storing each value as a variable will make it really difficult to use. You are far better off storing them in array like it already is in the $_POST array, or better yet a multi-dimensional array so you can reference a day at a time.

Comment: Also consider using an [off-the-shelf software package](http://mrbs.sourceforge.net) instead of writing your own.

Comment: @bumperbox Sounds like a better idea than the original (storing in a multi-d array). Off-the-shelf is something I cannot use as the project is one for coursework and requires me to code a system myself :) thank you Bumperbox!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to agree with bumperbox here - why create separate variables instead of using an array to store them all, as follows:

```
$day = array('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri');
$B = array('P1B', 'P2B', 'P3B', 'P4B', 'P5B', 'P6B');
$arr = array();

for ($l = 0; $l < count($day); ++$l) {
    for ($k = 0; $k < count($B); ++$k) {
        $days = $day[$l];
        $week = $B[$k];
        $arr[$days . $week] = $_POST["'" . $days.$week . "'"];
    }; 
};
```

Which would generate:

```
Array
(
    [MonP1B] => 
    [MonP2B] => 
    [MonP3B] => 
    ...
    [FriP4B] => 
    [FriP5B] => 
    [FriP6B] => 
)
```

And which you can access via `$arr['FriP5B']` for example.

Now, as to how you can improve your code, see this:

```
$days_of_the_week = array('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri');
$number_of_days = count($days_of_the_week);
$rooms = array('P1B', 'P2B', 'P3B', 'P4B', 'P5B', 'P6B');
$number_of_rooms = count($rooms);
$booked_day_room = array();

for ($day = 0; $day < $number_of_days; ++$day) {
    for ($room = 0; $room < $number_of_rooms; ++$room) {
        $days_room = $days_of_the_week[$day] . $rooms[$room];
        $booked_day_room[$days_room] = isset($_POST[$days_room]) ?: $_POST[$days_room];
    };
};

print_r($booked_day_room);
```

What we did:

1. [Used descriptive variable names](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/176585)
2. [Cached the `count()` function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9714237/1753963)
3. Stored everything in 1 array, so we don't have to chase 100 different variables

Why are we using an array over multiple variables? Multiple variables might be a bit faster, and they might use more or less the same memory, however from a code readability standpoint, you want one array as it is easier to keep track of in the code.

Comment: You might want to add isset around $_POST in-case there are non-existent keys

Comment: Good call, adding it in